# Vue.js class binded to object is not changing on object update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a number of buttons, being generated wuth v-for directive. all of them have initial class, based on the string from an object. I have an event, that is changing this string on button click. But the class is not being updated. What am i doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <v-layout>
        <v-btn v-for="cell in cells" :key='cell.id' v-bind:class='cell.color' 
            v-on:click='click(cell.id)'>
            <p v-if="cell.win">win</p>
            <p>{{cell.id}}</p>
        </v-btn>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            cells: {

            },
            winId: 0,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        generateCells() {
            this.winId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                this.cells[i] = {
                    id: i,
                    color: 'info'
                }
            }
        },
        click(id) {
            if (this.cells[id] == this.winId) {
                alert('you win');
                this.cells[id].color = 'success';
            } else {
                this.cells[id].color = 'warning';
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.generateCells();
    }
}

</script>
```

I expect the button class to be updated upon respected object update. The object .color prperty is updated but the class remains initial.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

Read more here: [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Vue provides an API to add properties to nested level objects and to make them reactive.

To do so, you can use

```
Vue.set(object, propertyName, value);
```

You can also use the `vm.$set` method

```
this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2);
```

So in your code, where you are setting the value of array you need to do

```
this.$set(this.cells, i, {
                           id: i,
                           color: 'info'
                         });
```

See the complete snippet below:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => {
      return {
        cells: {

        },
        winId: 0,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      generateCells() {
        this.winId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          this.$set(this.cells, i, {
            id: i,
            color: 'info'
          })
        }
      },
      click(id) {
        if (this.cells[id] == this.winId) {
          alert('you win');
          this.cells[id].color = 'success';
        } else {
          this.cells[id].color = 'warning';
        }
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.generateCells();
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.info {
  color: blue;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
}

.success {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-layout>
    <v-btn v-for="cell in cells" :key='cell.id' v-bind:class='cell.color' v-on:click='click(cell.id)'>
      <p v-if="cell.win">win</p>
      <p>{{cell.id}}</p>
    </v-btn>
  </v-layout>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in detail about data and methods in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html).

> It should be noted that properties in data are only reactive if they
> existed when the instance was created. That means if you add a new
> property,like:
>
> ```
> vm.b = 'hi'
> ```
>
> Then changes to b will not trigger any view updates.

you can use `Vue.set()` or `this.$set()` api when you set the prop value in loop.

or replace the whole object like:

```
var cells = {}
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cells[i] = {
    id: i,
    color: 'info'
    }
}
this.cells = cells
```

and then, in click callback:

```
var newCell = {}
if (this.cells[id] == this.winId) {
    alert('you win');
    newCell[id] = {id:id,color:'success'}
} else {
    newCell[id] = {id:id,color:'warning'}
}
this.cells = Object.assign({},this.cells,newCell)
```